# How to avoid space occurred on hiding element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I using jquery to hide and show two different forms.

**HTML Form 1:**

```
 <div id="form_1">
  <form>
     ........
  </form>
 </div>
```

**HTML Form 2:**

```
 <div id="form_2">
  <form>
     ........
  </form>
 </div>
```

These forms are arranged in one by one.

**My jQuery :**

**Scenario 1 :**

```
$('#form_1').hide();
$('#form_2').show();
```

**Scenario 2 :**

```
$('#form_1').show();
$('#form_2').hide()
```

Here, the **scenario 2** is working fine. Because, it's happened in general manner.

But **scenario 1** is come under different, here i use **$().hide()**, everything working fine, but there is some empty space that hold by **HTML Form 1**.

If I use **remove()**, then space get rejected. But i cant get back the previous element.

What's the solution for this ?

Thank in Advance !

Comment: use `display : none` in css

Comment: @guardio .hide() just sets display: none

Comment: could you provide a fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: I simulated the same thing & seems to be working fine. Check this [codepen example](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/XjXvor) I created. Can you replicate your issue here.

Comment: If you get empty space then the container for the form must have a height and/or width on it, therefore either remove those settings when you hide, or, remove them period and let the form create it's own space

Comment: The `hide()` hides the element irrespective of the height & width, so i don't think this should be an issue.

Comment: Thanks to all guys !
I fix it by tag rooting !